# Seeking the best way to constrain input to 4-digit year?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In a razor-syntax form in an MVC-4.5 website, where users can enter historical dates, if they enter 5/6/48, meaning 1948, or 1848, the system will change the year to 2014. Is there a way to change the client-side out-of-the-box validation so it requires a 4-digit year? If not, my choice would be to write another piece of jquery comparing input to a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answers having been offered for altering the client-side date validator to require a 4-digit year, I wrote the following jquery which appears to work side-by-side with the out-of-the-box validator -- probably because MVC's uses keyUp and mine uses blur:

```
 $("#BirthDate").blur(function () {
    var x = $(this).val();
    if (x.length > 0) {
        var idx = x.lastIndexOf("/");
        var sbs = x.substring(idx + 1, x.length);
        if (sbs.length < 4) {
            alert("Year must be 4 digits long");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, 
                 DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

//please adjust day and months to your culture, cannot derive what that is from your question

Assuming it is a jquery datepicker than you can specify format for it:

```
$(function(){ 
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: 'MM-dd-yyyy'});
 });
```

Comment: The culture is default (US) and putting in the annotation as you've suggested but MM/dd/yyyy really does not cause the client-side validator to call for a 4-digit year. The system just puts in 2014 if the user inputs a 2-digit year.

Comment: @JaneH updated answer, there are also other options for datepicker that might be of interest, e.g. date range etc

Comment: It is not a datepicker, because the years could be between 1600 and 2014. it is a razor editorfor, which could also be a textboxfor

Comment: how bout using dropdowns instead, with two for year?  first only having 16,...,20 as options

Comment: Can't do that because it makes for a 3-step date selection and there are 3 different places in the same form where that would have to happen.

Comment: you could do it with one textbox for year that had a valid range between 1600 and 2100?

Comment: Thank you, but I'm asking for ways to customize the validator, not to clutter up my design.